# What language is used in Linux scripts in dotfiles?

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I'm trying to figure out which language is used in Linux scripts to make the system more personal? I mean things like you put in the dotfiles — like `.vimrc`, or `.zshrc` — or to make a function for the terminal (like one that compiles a `.tex` file with `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` and then opens that `.pdf` with some reader).

Comment: Those are *Configuration* (or *run configuration*, e.g. `...rc`) files -- there is no language, it's just text that generally either sets some parameter directly or invokes a specific option (e.g. `.vimrc` with `syntax on`, or `.zshrc` with `compinit`) or associates a values with a variable, e.g. `.zshrc` with `HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history`. No set language for *config* files.

Answer (score 5):

What you call *dotfiles* are just configuration files of one or another program. So the "language" of each of those configuration files depends on the program that is going to use it.

In fact, that doesn't have to be a language, in general, hence the quotes in the previous paragraph. Those config files just have to match the format that the program that uses them expects. This occasionally means that configuarion files are required to use a specific language; an example is `.vimrc`, which has to use the Vimscript language (aka VimL).

Answer (score 2):

I think the term "Linux Scripts" will cause misunderstandment in here.

These *dotfiles* have a particular syntax for each one, but it's not a programming language.

It's allways a good idea to read the official documentation.

- https://www.vim.org/docs.php
- https://www.zsh.org/

For vimscript learning, I had a good experience with this one:

- https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/